# Heroku Local works fine and it is connected to Postgresql DB hosted by Heroku. Once attempt to deploy, got error code=H14 status=503

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I hope I can get some help in what should be my approach to deploy through Heroku.
I have a `Python` app with `Django` framework and `Postgresql` db. When I changed the environment from development to production, I used `gunicorn` to set up a wsgi path and then allowed the host in settings.py. I created a `Procfile` where manage.py lives, migrated my db to postgres and installed `whitenoise` middleware to collect static files.

When I run `Heroku local` to verify that my app is running, everything works correctly. Static files are located, can access the database and the localhost is ‘0.0.0.0’.

When I push to Heroku, I get the link where the app is released, and verifying deployment is done. Once I click on the link I see the error page displayed. ‘Heroku logs --tail’ gets me an error code=H14 status=503. I know It has to be an issue with Procfile because it is not in my root directory.

When I attempt to move Procfile to the root directory, gunicorn stops working because it doesn’t find a wsgi file nor manage.py.

How can I fix this conflict and what should be my approach? I don’t understand why everything works perfectly in `Heroku local`. Shouldn’t that be enough to confirm that everything runs fine and that it can be pushed to Heroku master?

```
>FINALPROJECT(root)
    > .vscode
    > project5
      > brainSkills
         > migrations
         > static
         > templates
         models.py
         urls.py
         views.py
      > project5
         _init_.py
         settings.py
         wsgi.py
         manage.py
         Procfile
         requirements.txt
    > venv
    .env
    .gitignore
    README.md
    requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Procfile` has to be in the project root, but with your folder structure there's an issue with that.

Keeping your `Procfile` you'll have to provide the wsgi file's location as a python-import like notation, eg: `gunicorn project5.wsgi`. From your project root you'll have to refer to it as `project5.project5.wsgi`, but your `project5` folder in root **is not a module**.

You can make it a valid python module folder by creating an empty `__init__.py` file inside `project5` (the one in the root)

The other solution is to change your project root itself to `project5`, but that's not suggested mid-way

**EDIT 1**
The reason why you got the `module project5.settings not found` error is because in your `wsgi.py` file change this line:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project5.settings')
```

to

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project5.project5.settings')
```

This should change the default settings module to the correct one

**EDIT 2**

Everything would be much simpler if your project root was the same as the django app's project root, the easiest solution is to simply move all the files like `README.md` and `.env` into the `project5` folder and use it as your project root, the only downside being you'll have to reinitialise your git repository, also, if your doing this make sure to change your `wsgi.py` file to what it was earlier

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you suggested. When I run `gunicorn project5.project5.wsgi` from the root directory I get *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project5.settings'* ...Any other suggestions for these issues? Thanks. @FalseDev

Comment: Now, I run into a ModuleNotFoundError for one of my apps. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'brainSkills'`. Do you have any documentation that you suggest I could read about to solve this problem? I really want to get this app working. I appreciate your help. :) @FalseDev